# If and only if with two conditions?

Tags: notation

Would it make sense to write a statement saying that, for example:
$A = B$ if and only if $f(A,B) = 1$ or $g(A,B) = 2$ ?

Comment: The short answer is "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense because we have two boolean expressions.

Answer (score 0):

It does make sense. It is a matter of taste and/or context whether you would prefer to write

> $A=B$ if and only if $f(A,B)\in\{1,2\}$

instead.